# Miktex begin document error

Tags: errors, revtex, compilation-error, miktex-update

I update the MikTeX distribution from 2.9 to 21.6. A simple file that was previously compiled
without any problem:

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\begin{document} 

\title{\textbf{Width }}
\author{H} 
\email{h@aps} 
\affiliation{Es} 

\author{A} 
\email{v@aps} 
\affiliation{Dep}

\date{\today} 

\begin{abstract}
We study 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 

\noindent
\section{Introduction} 
%
During 
%
\end{document}
```

Now produces this error message

```
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.6 \begin{document}
```

Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

I have read all posts abut similar problems but do not find the way to
fix it. Any idea what to do?
Thanks

This is the log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=latex 2021.6.25)  25 JUN 2021 12:42
entering extended mode
**./Width.tex
(Width.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
 Copyright (c) 2001 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <ogawa@teleport.com>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david@dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 596.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count182
\@tbpen=\count183
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box50
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1610.
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
\c@linecount=\count184
\output=\toks16
\@protection@box=\box51
\@topmark@saved=\toks17
\footins@saved=\box52
\pagesofar=\box53
\footbox=\box54
\pagegrid@col=\count185
Class revtex4 Info: Incorporating package {textcase}  [1998/11/12 v0.06 Text on
ly upper/lower case changing (DPC)]. on input line 3682.
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@affil=\count186
\absbox=\box55
\c@part=\count187
\c@section=\count188
\c@subsection=\count189
\c@subsubsection=\count190
\c@paragraph=\count191
\c@subparagraph=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\c@figure=\count193
\c@table=\count194

(C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip49
\bibsep=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count195
)
\widetext@top=\box56
\widetext@bot=\box57

(C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\revsymb.sty
Package: revsymb 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documenta
tion)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 118.
))
(C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\aps.rtx
File: aps.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentatio
n)
)
(C:\Users\Alfredo\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/revtex4\12pt.rtx
File: 12pt.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentati
on)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\epsfig.sty
Package: epsfig 2017/06/25 v1.7b (e)psfig emulation (SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/12/05 v1.2c Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks18
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2021/03/04 v1.4d Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 107.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen138
\Gin@req@width=\dimen139
)
\epsfxsize=\dimen140
\epsfysize=\dimen141
)
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.6 \begin{document}
                    
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvips.def
File: l3backend-dvips.def 2021-05-07 L3 backend support: dvips
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box58
\g__pdf_backend_object_int=\count196
\l__pdf_backend_content_box=\box59
\l__pdf_backend_model_box=\box60
\g__pdf_backend_annotation_int=\count197
\g__pdf_backend_link_int=\count198
\g__pdf_backend_link_sf_int=\count199
) (Width.aux)
\openout1 = `Width.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: Unrecognized LaTeX tabular. Please update this document cla
ss! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 32.

[1] [2] (Width.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2414 strings out of 478839
 33164 string characters out of 2857897
 343673 words of memory out of 3000000
 20396 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 407894 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,7n,80p,220b,319s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on Width.dvi (2 pages, 2092 bytes).
```

Comment: use the updated revtex4-2 and it should be fine. (unrelated don't use `\usepackage{epsfig}` in any document written after 1993 I wrote it then as a legacy wrapper for the 1980s LaTeX2.09 package of the same name.

Comment: That said , even using the older revtex4.cls as  you posted above  it runs without error in an up to date texlive (sorry I can't test miktex)

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried revtex4-2 and it worked. What is hard to understand to me is why updating miktex does not produce the same output. I am using two laptops, one with miktex 2.9, everything is fine, the second miktex updated, first file first problem. I have hundred of tex files produced with miktex 2.9 and I am now afraid updating miktex could generate much more problems. There should a way of fixing this problem without touchinf the file, perhaps updating some packages, but I tried everyhting I could for almost one week and I am just got convinced I am getting too old!!!

Comment: Can we please see the entire log of your compilation of this very example?

Comment: updating miktex should not be  a problem: your log file will probably show that you have older versions in your path so you are getting an inconsistent set, it isn't really anything releated to miktex but to the version of the latex format you have and if you are inputting compatible versions of revtex.

Comment: I updated the post with the entire log file, hope you can see it!! I am new in this business and there are things do not know how to do properly. Sorry for that!!!!!

Comment: But the original version of revtex is so simple that I do not know where the problem can arise from. Revtex was designed to produce no problems, and the file does not contain nothing more than the first page of an article file.

Comment: Have you tried updating miktex in both miktex user mode and miktex admin mode (if you look at the paths in the log file you'll notice that you're using data from two locations `appdata` and `Program File`. The each of the two miktex modes only update **one** of these. So old versions may linger. For example I have a newer version of `revtex.cls` on my version (the version year of 2001 for revtex seems wrong, I think that was fixed in v4.0a)

Comment: I don't know if it can be related, but in this new version of MikTeX seem that there is a reorganization of the folders. I have to manually uninstall and install some packages from the console for make the things to work.

Comment: If you have old stuff lingering in `appdata` they takes precedence over any newer package versions found under `Program Files`, thus it is very very important to update both.

Comment: Regarding the admin and user modes and checked again the same revtex files are installed in both places, I could send you the log file with miktex 2.9 and is using files from appdata and Program File and it works.

Comment: revtex4 is now obsolete so miktex probably neither installs it not updates it, if you want a newer version you will have to get it from ctan manually.

Comment: I do think has to do with miktex, but I did instal manually old revetx files .... Never found a problem like that..... :-(

Comment: I install old revtex files manually, as on the other side I used to do with miktex 2.9!!!! and also in my lynux distributions......

Comment: I think I am getting too obsolete without any possible update...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer revtex is not marked obsolete on CTAN and both miktex and texlive are listed to have it. It is revtex4.1 that is listed as obsolte. No idea why.

Comment: @daleif hm, perhaps I mixed up revtex4.0 and revtex4, not sure if the last has been updated at all.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ahh, no I made a mistake. I'm looking at `revtex` the OP is using `revtex4`  which one cannot even search on CTAN.

Comment: miktex doesn't have the newest revtex4.cls, on texlive I have `revtex4 2020/09/30 v4.0a`, on miktex I have `revtex4 2001/08/03 v4.0`. You could open an issue at the miktex github and ask for an update, but better is to use the newest revtex4-2.